# Issue about socket.io real-time text display

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to use node.js and socket.io library to establish websocket connection between client and server. The server will generate a random number per second and it will emit a event which allow client to detect.

The problem is the client(a webpage) can detect the event and display the random number send by server, but it's not real-time. I had to refresh my browser in order to display a new random number.  I want the client to display the random number in real-time but I don't know why my websocket app appears to be not real-time.

Server(main.js) source code:

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);

app.get('/', function(req, res){                  
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

randomNum();

function randomNum(){
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('random', Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
    });
    setInterval(randomNum, 1000);
}

server.listen(8080);
```

Client(index.html) source code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Websocket</title>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
var socket = io();
socket.on('random', function(data){
    document.getElementById("displayNum").innerHTML = data;
});
</script>

</head>

<body>
<p id="displayNum"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't do this:

```
function randomNum(){
    io.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('random', Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1));
    });
    setInterval(randomNum, 1000);
}
```

You set io.on connection every 1s. You should make function for emiting your random and set interval outside this function